# why my MacBook air 2020 start using more energy after I use Xcode ,Even when I Quit Xcode?

Tags: xcode, flutter, macos

I had noticed my mac start Draining energy after I used Xcode simulator even after Quitting App .
i did test after using Xcode i closed all apps and and played Video for 30 min with 45% screen brightness It took 9% !
So i did a Restart ,This time it only took 3% !

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please check `Activity Monitor` for battery hunger apps (Go to `Energy` tab and sort by `12 hr power` column). It's not possible to say is XCode with only an empirical testing.

Comment: thank you :) ,I used activity monitor , the thing is everything looks fine ! no app drain  energy but in action a brand new laptop with 19cycle shouldn't take 9% for playing 30min of video with half brightness !and after restart takes 3% for same operation  and ofc you are right about my test being empirical but still the results shows magnificent difference

Answer (score 1):

The app was probably still open in the background, which still consumes battery. Restarting the laptop closes all open background apps, hence it consumed less battery once restarted.

Try Force quitting the app next time you want to close it.

Comment: I am pretty sure Xcode was totally closed , I think this is a bug or smh , I have seen this problem in some apple forum webSite / also after restarting laptop energy usage was totally normal as before its just when I do open Xcode battery usage goes up also laptop get hot normally EVEN after I close it completely